# Is negating inequality with NULL different from negating?

Tags: c, null

[This](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) OpenSSL example contains code like this:

```
const SSL_METHOD* method = SSLv23_method();
if(!(NULL != method)) handleFailure();
```

Is this not-NULL check different from the following?

```
if(!method) handleFailure();
```

The only reason I can see for their way is that it could be closer to the semantics: "it *should* be not-NULL (`NULL != method`), but if that's not the case (the `!`) then we should handle the failure."

Comment: @2501 So I'm wrong. I cancel. I remember something like _it doesn't have to be represented with all-zero bits_

Comment: @LPs Representation is not the same as value.

Comment: @LPs I can't remember off the top of my head if `NULL` is guaranteed to be zero or not, but what *would* the `!` operator do if not check for a null pointer?

Comment: @2501 Yes, Now I know it... ;)

Comment: @LPs: You remember correct, but all null-pointer values compare equal and non-equal to valid pointer values.

Comment: @Quentin If `NULL` can be allowed to be different than `0`, then `!address` does not check if address is `NULL`. BTW the problem does not exists because `NULL` must be equal to `0`

Comment: @Quentin: The **macro** `NULL` contains a _null pointer constant_. Which is not to be confused with the actual representation. That is all a bit confusing and burdened with legacies.

Comment: @lp The source code representation of a nullpointer is not the same as the actual runtime (in memory or register or whatever) representation, that's the thing you seem to be missing. When you do `void *a = (void *) 0;` it's totally possible that on some architecture the variable gets set to `0xfeedf00dcafebabe`. That would require code like `if(!a)` to compile to instructions that check if the variable's value is equal to `0xfeedf00dcafebabe`. At the source level, we still act as if the null pointer is zero, logically.

Comment: @Olaf my point is, regardless of what `NULL` is, that the `!` operator has a specific "overload" for pointers. You can't divide by a pointer or bitwise-not it, but you can boolean-not it. The only sensible thing `!`-for-pointers would do is check for null.

Comment: @unwind Ty, I got it now. My confusion arose due to an "ancient" experience of a F...nny old platform where, I swear, `NULL` was `-1`... ;)

Comment: @Quentin: More exactly: you can check for a _null pointer_, resp. the pointer is converted to a boolean (but not type `_Bool`!) result for such expressions. One could see it as being overloaded, but I'd be careful about that in C.

Comment: I think, your assumption about being "closer to the semantics" is close to the truth... However, the line `if(NULL == cert) handleFailure();` doesn't follow this paradigma. OTOH, OpenSSL isn't really a reference for good coding...

Comment: @Lundin I see nothing in that Q&A that contradicts what I already think I know, so I'll just assume that I'm awful at expressing myself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NULL` is guaranteed to be a *null pointer constant*. Not to be confused with a *null pointer* (which could in theory have a non-zero representation). A null pointer constant can be defined as either `(void*)0` or `0`.

`!(void*)0` and `!0` both give the value `1` so either version is guaranteed to work.

However, it is considered poor practice to use logic operators on pointer operands. An explicit comparison with `NULL` makes the intention of the programmer much clearer - it is a form of self-documenting code and is therefore good practice.

Comment: @chux No, it can explicitly only be `(void*)0` or `0` as per C11 6.3.2.3. It can't be anything else.